# Google Firestore: Custom auth mechanism

Tags: android, ssl, ssl-certificate, google-cloud-firestore, mitmproxy

I want to create user based app with firestore, but I don't want to enforce users to login through Google or Facebook or (damn) email and password.

Aim:

1. User logging in my app by vk.com (social network) sdk
2. I'm getting vk.com user id and that is the key to check user can for example write document in collection.
3. I have not found any info in the firestore doc about SSL-Pinning, is it safe to use firestore Android SDK and not worry about MITM (man in the middle) attacks by proxy?

Comment: Ok, if someone is interested in doing that:
I did Google SignIn button and firestore now has collection "users", which documents ids equals users google account Id and every user has his social network id as a firestore document field

Comment: also you can remove sign in button.
just use unique string as unique@some-persistent-string.com and perform firebaseauth with email and password. )